# Why does Python3 use 'surrogatepass' file-system error handler on Windows?

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, filesystems

For Python 3 (3.8 and previous versions back to 3.6), `surrogatepass` is the default error handler.

This can [cause problems](https://developer.blender.org/T74510) for users with file-paths that don't match this encoding.

Why does windows use `surrogatepass` instead of `surrogateescape` as other platforms do (Linux, macOS), which can handle these bytes. eg:

```py
>>> import sys

>>> sys.getfilesystemencoding(), sys.getfilesystemencodeerrors()
('utf-8', 'surrogateescape')
>>>
>>> # This raises an error:
>>>
>>> b'C:\\Users\\me\\OneDrive\\\xe0\xcd\xa1\xca\xd2\xc3\\my.txt'.decode('utf-8', errors="surrogatepass")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 24: invalid continuation byte

>>> # Compared to:

>>> b'C:\\Users\\me\\OneDrive\\\xe0\xcd\xa1\xca\xd2\xc3\\my.txt'.decode('utf-8', errors="surrogateescape")
'C:\\Users\\me\\OneDrive\\\udce0͡\udcca\udcd2\udcc3\\my.txt'
```

---

*Note, at a guess I would assume this might be necessary because the underlying NTFS filesystem uses UTF-16 instead of null terminated bytes, requiring some constraints on Python's filesystem encoding not present on Linux/macOS.*